# Erro during insert

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, insert, sequelize.js

I am executing this:

```
const Seq = require(`sequelize`);

const seq = new Seq(`sistemadecadastro`, `root`, `Dev01891`, {
  host: `localhost`,
  dialect: `mysql`,
});

seq
  .authenticate()
  .then(function () {
    console.log(`Conectado ao MySQL com sucesso!`);
  })
  .catch(function (erro) {
    console.log(`Erro na conexao com MySQL: ` + erro);
  });

const postagem = seq.define(`postagens`, {
  titulo: {
    type: Seq.STRING,
  },
  conteudo: {
    type: Seq.TEXT,
  },
});

postagem.sync({ force: true });

postagem.create({
  titulo: `AVISO`,
  conteudo: `Four values - border-radius: 15px 50px 30px 5px; (first value applies to to`,
});
```

but I cant add a new record because the INSERT is happening 'before' the sequelize creates the table.

Console output:

```
PS C:\Projects\TestNodeMySql> node testMySQL.js
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `postagens`;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `postagens` (`id`,`titulo`,`conteudo`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?);
Conectado ao MySQL com sucesso!
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `postagens` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `titulo` VARCHAR(255), `conteudo` TEXT, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Table 'sistemadecadastro.postagens' doesn't exist
    at Query.formatError (C:\Projects\TestNodeMySql\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:244:16)
    at handler (C:\Projects\TestNodeMySql\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:51:23)
    at Prepare.onResult (C:\Projects\TestNodeMySql\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:604:11)
    at Prepare.execute (C:\Projects\TestNodeMySql\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:30:14)
    at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Projects\TestNodeMySql\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:417:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Projects\TestNodeMySql\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:75:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Projects\TestNodeMySql\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\TestNodeMySql\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:82:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)

Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `postagens`
```

I am new in node.js and sequelize. This part of code is just for my study purposes. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your order of operations is:

1. Drop table.
2. Insert into table.
3. Create table.

Reverse the order of steps 2 and 3.

If this is async code you may need to wait for the create table step to complete before attempting an insert. Don't let them run in an arbitrary order.

Sequelize is Promise driven so this is often as simple as an `await` or a `then()` chain, like:

```
await postagem.sync({ force: true });

postagem.create({
  titulo: `AVISO`,
  conteudo: `Four values - border-radius: 15px 50px 30px 5px; (first value applies to to`,
});
```

Where this is within an `async` function of some kind. Notice that [`sync`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-sync) returns a `Promise`, which means it can run out-of-order if you're not careful.